# jquery unix time, timestamp узнать прошла ли минута

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно узнать, прошла ли минута в функции localStorageTime

В storage я записываю timestamp, далее вызываю функцию localStorageTime и там хочу узнать, прошла ли минута от времени localStorage.setItem('user-online-timestamp', timestamp) до текущего timestamp

Как это правильно реализовать?

```
const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
localStorage.setItem('user-online-timestamp', timestamp);
localStorageTime();

function localStorageTime()
    {
        const timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
        const time = localStorage.getItem('user-online-timestamp');
        console.log(time);
       //TODO прошла ли минута
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

вот так преобразуйте

```
const time = localStorage.getItem('user-online-timestamp');
let localStorageTime = new Date(+time);
```

а скрипт будет примерно такой

```
const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
if (localStorage.getItem('user-online-timestamp') == undefined) {
    localStorage.setItem('user-online-timestamp', timestamp);
}
localStorageTime();
setTimeout( localStorageTime, 60000);

function localStorageTime()
{
    const timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
    const time = localStorage.getItem('user-online-timestamp');
    let localStorageTime = new Date(+time);
    if (timeStamp - localStorageTime >= 60000) {
        console.log("минута прошла");
    } else {
        console.log("минута не прошла");
    }

    console.log(timeStamp - localStorageTime);
}
```